# web client to get progressive server response - how to?

Tags: jquery, servlets

Been trying for this, perhaps efforts are not heading right, so would appreciate any help.

My HTML page has a button and a div. When I click the button, my server has to keep pushing numbers with couple of seconds interval, and as server pushes the numbers, I need them on the div, progressively, in-synch with server's status. How to achieve this? Tried using the AsyncContext, but this behaves similar to response and flushes whole output at the end which is not we want.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync(request, response);
    ac.start(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                try {
                    ac.getResponse().getWriter().print("Hello-"+i);
                    System.out.println("written hello");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ac.complete();
        }
    });
}
```

And my HTML is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="../js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    function ajax_stream() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                $("#mydiv").text($("#mydiv").val+xhr.responseText);
            };
            xhr.open("GET", "../test", true);
            xhr.send();
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <button onclick="ajax_stream();">Start Ajax Streaming</button>
 <div id="mydiv">Starting : </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure if my understanding on this concept is correct, but this progressive state of server response to be captured by client is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: More like trying to get something like this: http://www.binarytides.com/ajax-based-streaming-without-polling/

Comment: `ac.getResponse().flushBuffer();` after `ac.getResponse().getWriter().print("Hello-"+i);` felt interesting initially. But now the issue is response is cumulative i.e. initially we see Hello-1, then we see Hello-1Hello-2, later Hello-1Hello-2Hello-3 and so on...

How can I just view the response for that call instead of accumulative? Sounds like responseText will include everything servlet returns, but I am only interested in latest output. How to fix this?